# Are there ways to specify the conversion character for double and float in C without having to know the number of its decimal?

Tags: c

In C I have learned that to specify a conversion character for `float` or `double` I will have to use `%.xf`. Is it possible to not specify and display `double or float` without having to count up the number of its decimal.

EDIT:Sorry if I am not understanding this because I am just a beginner at programming in general, and C is my first language.

```
double reallyBigPi = 3.1415914159141591415914159;
printf("Big Pi = %f\n\n", reallyBigPi);
```

My goal is to print out this input but using the suggested %f I was only able to get Big Pi = 3.141591. So in the end if I want the get that amount I will have to count up the decmial point?

Comment: Do you really want to pring a double with 26 significant decimal digits? I can only wish you lots of good luck...

Comment: @n.m. This was just an example. While learning the concept of C I got question that the video didn't went into so I decided to ask it here. I don't think I will be using these kind of number too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, neither the C nor the C++ standard libraries expose an interface to Dragon4 (*) (or an improved algorithm) which would correctly determine the number of fractional decimal numbers from a binary floating point representing a decimal number. The libraries are required (by IEEE 754) to correctly format the values, though.

Obviously, determining the number of fractional digits is not equivalent to omitting the precision. Simply omitting the precision behaves the same as specifying the default precision (which, I think, is 6).

You may be able to use [Double Conversion](https://code.google.com/p/double-conversion/) as that *does* expose an interface determining the number of decimals. I found Double Conversion relatively hard to use, though.

(*) Dragon4 is an algorithm described in ["How to print floating-point numbers accurately"](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=989431&dl=ACM&coll=DL&CFID=737679217&CFTOKEN=13091991). Note that this link is to an ACM site which asks for payment for the article. I don't have a link to a [legal] free source of the paper.

Comment: A paywall external link is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: @Olaf: this article predates the era where everything was freely shared. There may be a free source of this article but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Anyway, it should not be in an answer. Remember that an answer has to be self-contained, or at least include the general principle. Maybe you can elaborate.

Comment: @Olaf: The first sentence actually _is_ the answer to the question: "Is there anyway way ...". It is a fancy way with pointers to say "no". The question was _not_ "What's the algorithm to ..." although the answer does mention those.

Comment: @Mapring: There are algorithms which can determine the appropriate number of fractional decimals to be used when formatting a [binary] floating point number assuming the value stored in the floating point number is a correctly converted decimal value (there is a companion for the article mentioned above for accurately reading floating point numbers). If you have a "really big PI" you'll be out of luck anyway: I assume "big" refers to the number of digits as there is just one PI and its value is well-known. Floating points are fixed size representation capable of representing just a few digits.

Comment: OK, I guess I will have to have a look at that seeing that there are literally no other way.

Comment: If it's important that you be able to "round trip" the output and get exactly the same number when you read it back in, then look at the `%a` specifier.  Not very human readable, though.